# Django/Python: post_save signal - expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django, django-tenants

I have a post_save signal which is failing with 'expected string or bytes-like object'. I am not sure why, it is being caused by the call to create_user below:-

This is to create a user within a tenant schema for a newly created tenant:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Client)
def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    tenant=instance
    with schema_context(tenant):
        name = 'name'
        email = 'name@email.com'
        password = 'passwordexample'
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(name, email, password)
```

The underlying user manager which throws the exception is

```
def create_user(self, name, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        name = self.normalize_email(name)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(name=name, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

This seems to fail on user.save() in the above manager

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: can you post full error_trace

Comment: And `CustomUser` and `Client` models

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing not in Custom user manager it is in

```
 with schema_context(tenant)
```

as this schema_context takes schema name not tenant
so I think you need to pass schema_name
or if you know tenants use
the following instead

```
from django_tenants.utils import tenant_context

with tenant_context(tenant):
    # All commands here are ran under the schema from the `tenant` object
```